# Error on realpath() on '/var/lib/mysql-files' (Error 2 - No such file or directory)

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux, lamp

I am using Ubuntu to configure Wordpress on WSL. Currently, I am trying to install MySQL as part of the LAMP Stack using the following as per [this tutorial](https://hellojason.net/blog/how-to-setup-wordpress-locally-on-windows-subsystem-for-linux/):

```
sudo usermod -d /var/lib/mysql/ mysql
sudo service mysql start
```

When I run the second command, I see "fail" in red appear (ie. mysql won't start). Here is what the Error Log looks like:

```
2021-09-05T08:17:59.936284Z mysqld_safe Logging to '/var/log/mysql/error.log'.
2021-09-05T08:17:59.951837Z mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /var/lib/mysql
mysqld: Error on realpath() on '/var/lib/mysql-files' (Error 2 - No such file or directory)
2021-09-05T08:17:59.962000Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010139] [Server] Changed limits: max_open_files: 1024 (requested 8161)
2021-09-05T08:17:59.962006Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010142] [Server] Changed limits: table_open_cache: 431 (requested 4000)
2021-09-05T08:18:00.172509Z 0 [Warning] [MY-011068] [Server] The syntax 'expire-logs-days' is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use binlog_expire_logs_seconds instead.
2021-09-05T08:18:00.172578Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010095] [Server] Failed to access directory for --secure-file-priv. Please make sure that directory exists and is accessible by MySQL Server. Supplied value : /var/lib/mysql-files
2021-09-05T08:18:00.172626Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
2021-09-05T08:18:00.178880Z mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /run/mysqld/mysqld.pid ended
```

Edit- Here is what I get when I run the following commands:

```
root@DESKTOP-P44T17P:~# stat /var/lib/mysql-files
stat: cannot stat '/var/lib/mysql-files': No such file or directory
root@DESKTOP-P44T17P:~# grep user /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf
user            = mysql
```

It does not look the mysql-files directory exists.

Ubuntu 20.04.2

Comment: Does the directory exist? And is it accessible by the mysqld service?

Comment: Can you check two things?  First, `stat /var/lib/mysql-files` (include in the question).  Then `grep user /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf`.  Thanks!

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds I added the above. It does not look like the mysql-files directory exists but I'm not sure what to do. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Wisely And I would assume that you've tried uninstalling and reinstalling?  I went through those same instructions and didn't have any problem on WSL with Ubuntu 20.04.  In searching I found a few cases that looked similar to yours, but most had to do with Docker, which isn't a factor in your installation.  The remaining one was due to the mysql user not having permissions to that directory.  But in your case, the directory doesn't even exist.  So I'm kind of at a loss.  At the least, `sudo apt remove lamp-server^ && sudo apt install lamp-server^` might let you spot an error in the install.

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds I'll try that. I [re-posted](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1362484/error-on-realpath-on-var-lib-mysql-files-error-2-no-such-file-or-directo?noredirect=1#comment2336726_1362484) on Ask Ubuntu and apparently the tutorial I used was running on Ubuntu 16.04. Not sure if this is the problem, especially since you didn't have any issues, but I will do as you advised first.

Answer (score 0):

it might be your log folder deleted for some reason. make sure there's /var/log/mysql folder. if it's don't just make new one with mysql ownership.

Answer (score -2):

Ensure the directory /var/lib/mysql-files exists and MySQL should start.
You can try:

> sudo mkdir /var/lib/mysql-files